# Phanto .application style in Vuetify Vue CLI3 project

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a vuetify project initiated with Vue CLI3.

I see that my body fonts are overwritten by a class called `.application` 
This class style is nowhere to be found which leads me to believe it comes with the framework.

I also have a file called vuetify.ts with the following content:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib'
import 'vuetify/src/stylus/app.styl'

Vue.use(Vuetify, {
  iconfont: 'md',
})
```

How do I add custom already-made scss file to be the main style sheet including writing over the framework font families, etc?

I tried this solution which does not work: https://medium.com/@jacobedawson/vuetify-vue-cli-3-change-default-font-a70c22adc55

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Here is some of my existing scss file that is ready-made.

```
@import url("https://use.typekit.net/upu2cxc.css");
$font-family-sans-serif:      proxima-nova, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji" !default;
$font-family-sans-serif-extra-condensed:  proxima-nova-extra-condensed,  -apple-system, sans-serif;

$font-family-monospace:       SFMono-Regular, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, "Liberation Mono", "Courier New", monospace !default;
$font-family-serif:           Georgia, serif;
$font-family-base:            $font-family-sans-serif;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

In a standard vue cli framework, the `app.vue` file is a good `source of truth` for app level styles.

In `app.vue`

```
<style lang='scss'>
@import url("https://use.typekit.net/upu2cxc.css");
$font-family-sans-serif:      proxima-nova, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji" !default;
$font-family-sans-serif-extra-condensed:  proxima-nova-extra-condensed,  -apple-system, sans-serif;

$font-family-monospace:       SFMono-Regular, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, "Liberation Mono", "Courier New", monospace !default;
$font-family-serif:           Georgia, serif;
$font-family-base:            $font-family-sans-serif;
</style>
```

Comment: That seems to work, but only with !important as somewhere .application class overwrites everything. No idea where this is as global search didn't turn p anything.

Comment: What in particular needs the `!important` modifier?

Comment: Instead of `!important`, you can wrap your imports inside `.application` (and or other classes) to increase specificity.  BTW `.application` is provided by vuetify.